# Effectively copy pasting (kill/yanking) with emacs running in tmux on Mac OS X

Tags: osx, tmux, emacs, clipboard

I am attempting to run emacs from within tmux (with emacs keybindings to avoid context switching) on Mac Os X and am having a real hard time getting copy/paste to work right. I am also attempting to configure tmux and emacs to both share their respective clipboards with the operating system.

the relevant sections of my tmux config:

```
set-option -g mouse on
set-option -g default-command "reatatach-to-user-namespace -l bash"
setw -g mode-keys emacs
bind-key -n -t emacs-copy M-w copy-pipe "reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"
bind-key -n C-y run "xclip -o | tmux load-buffer - ; tmux paste-buffer"
```

And of my emacs config:

```
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard t x-select-enable-primary t)
```

This has the following effects:

1) I can copy and paste in my tmux with emacs buttons (`M-w`, `C-y`)

2) Whenever I attempt to select a region in my emacs (with `C-Space` for example), it also selects my line number from `linum-mode`

3) I can copy things that I select with my mouse inside emacs into my system clipboard AND the kill ring( e.g. selecting text with my mouse and hitting `M-w` causes me to be able to past in my browser/other applications with `Command+V` (I'm on a Mac) AND in emacs/tmux with `C-y`)

4) Selecting a region (with problem 2 baked in to boot) with `C-Space` and using either `C-w` or `M-w`, or just killing with `C-k` does not result in pastable result, either in the kill ring, or on the system clipboard.

Is there any way to fix problems 2/4 without getting rid of desirable properties 1/3?

Thanks so much!